# Selecting based on list of numeric ranges in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a predefined list of integer ranges, something like 16...32, 24...40, and so on.

Every row in the table is having one of those ranges in one column `current`. There should be also a column `accepted` that has list of ranges. Both columns are not directly related in any way.

The goal is when I have a row A with eg. `current = 16...32` I want to find all other rows where `accepted` includes that specific `current` range. Ideally, do that as part of the same query.

In my naive approach, I would have a separate table with those ranges identified with ID and then reference by that. But seeing how robust the Postgres is, I keep wondering if there is an easier way.

### Clarification

This is the way I would do it, but it feels too bulky. Does Postgres offer something more concise?

```
CREATE TABLE "ranges" (
  id integer
  min integer -- just for clarity
  max integer -- isn't considered for querying
)

CREATE TABLE "users" (
  id integer
  currentRangeId integer -- references ranges
)

CREATE TABLE "userRanges" (
  userId integer -- references users
  rangeId integer -- references ranges
)
```

In most cases, I will have `userId` on input, I need to find its `currentRangeId` and then on the output I am expecting list of other `userId` where `rangeId = currentRangeId`.

Comment: What data type are these ranges? Ideally you could add a `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I am not sure really, I see there are some range related data types, but those cannot be lists? Maybe I am wrong about it and it's not possible to have in a single table?

Comment: @FredyC You could store an array of ranges and use `current <@ ANY accepted`. But probably normalising the schema to get rid of the lists will be better

Comment: I am not sure how I could get rid of the list except a separate referential table. Users can select multiple ranges.

Comment: @FredyC If your users can *select* ranges, ranges are defined before, are immutable and multiple users can select the same range, then yes definitely go for a separate table. Or does every use define and edit their own list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use arrays:

- `current` would be an `integer`
- `accepted` would be an `integer[]`

Then the query could be like this:

```
WHERE current = ANY (accepted)
```

Comment: Hm, I am not seeing how to use `int4range` as a list of `accepted` ranges?

Comment: Ok - what exactly do you mean by "includes that specific current range". Seems to be something different.

Comment: Imagine a crude way where each that range has some ID. Then in a table I will have columns `current` that is referencing single ID and then `accepted` that refers to list of those IDs. Then I need to write query that looks if `currentId` is included with `acceptedIds` of other rows.

Comment: I've updated OP with some native approach clarification.

Comment: So you would recommend a separate table with ranges as well? I guess Posgres isn't that robust after all :) Thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't see the connection with robustness. I just picked `integer` because that seemed to be what you wanted. It will work just the same with `int4range` and `int4range[]`.